# How do on-disk databases handle file reading and writing on a file system level?

Tags: c++, c, database, sqlite, filesystems

Suppose I were to write my own database in c++ and suppose I would use a binary tree or a hash map as the underlying datastructure. How would I handle updates to this datastructure?

1) Should I first create the binary tree and then somehow persist it onto a disk? And every time data has to be updated I need to open this file and update it? Wouldn't that be a costly operation?

2) Is there a way to directly work on the binary tree without loading it into memory and then persisting again?

3) How does SQLite and Mysql deal with it?

4) My main question is, how do databases persist huge amounts of data and concurrently make updates to it without opening and closing the file each time.

Comment: It's pretty rare to see a disk based store using binary trees. B trees and extendable hashing are probably the most common approaches. It's also common to just leave the file(s) open for the duration of a session instead of repeatedly opening and closing them for each operation.

Comment: I know that MySQL uses binary trees and I also know that it's not an in memory DB, how does MySQL work then? What if the size of binary tree is more than my ram, and some operations need to be done on it, where does the engine run these computations?

Comment: You might keep a separate log file persisting all the transactions (i. e. *appending* them to a file - well, the writing ones only, of course). Only from time to time, you'd create a new data base file, storing all changes to and throwing away the old data base file and log file. In case of a crash or any other problem, you could replay all the transactions from the logs...

Comment: B Tree != Binary tree. InnoDB, the default storage engine for MySQL, uses the former for indexing.

Comment: If I keep a log file persisting transactions and I have not yet updated my database and a user has queried my database, wouldn't my database return wrong values? Do you then mean everytime I get a query request, I must update my database first?
@Shawn, alright, but are queries and updates in MySQL run on RAM? if so, when is the data actually written to disk?

Comment: Anyways, only portions of a big database will typically be loaded into memory at a time. There's usually ways to tune cache sizes and the like to control just how much.

Comment: @Shawn what If I have one million records (and only half a million fits in memory) and client wants to search for a record? Do I then maintain two B Trees and load each one? Also, I'm still not sure when to write data to the disk i.e when to "close" the file. What do you mean by open for the duration of a session? Until the database is turned off?

Comment: Also, Is there a standard book where I can learn these concepts?

Comment: Note: MySQL and other databases are _Database Managers._ That means that clients connect to the _manager_ and not to the database. The manager ensures all clients and the database are synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Databases see the disk or file as one big bock device and manage blocks in M-way Balanced Trees. They insert/update/delete records in these blocks and flush dirty blocks to disk again. They manage allocation tables of free blocks so the database does not need to be rewritten on each access. As RAM memory is expensive but fast, pages are kept in a RAM cache. Separate indexes (either separate files or just blocks) manage quick access based on keys. Blocks are often the native allocation size of the underlying filesystem (e.g. cluster size). Undo/redo logs are maintained for atomicity. etc.

Much more to be told and this question actually belongs on Computer Science Stack Exchange. For more information read Horowitz & Sahni, "Fundamentals of datastructures", p.496.

As to your questions:

1. You open it once and keep open while your database manager is running. You allocate storage as needed and maintain an M-way tree as described above.
2. Yes. You read blocks that you keep in a cache.
3. and 4: See above.

Comment: Is there any example code that you can point me to for accessing memory blocks? Also can you recommend any other textbook or sources, I'm not able to get hold of the one you suggested. Also, what topic does my question come under in computer science, it would be helpful for google searches and book recommendations.

Comment: https://www.db-book.com/db6/slide-dir/PPT-dir/ch10.ppt and https://www.db-book.com/db6/slide-dir/PPT-dir/ch11.ppt and possibly other chapters. But the matter is complex!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would not do file I/O to access the data.  Use `mmap` to map the data into the virtual address space of the process and let the OS block cache take care of the reads and writes.